# Why "height: auto;" doesn't work when i use "float:left"?

Tags: html, css

i have three responsive columns, and i want to add a wrap div for those divs.

i already created this wrap div, but it only works with pixel values, and i dont want to use pixels because i'm trying to build a responsive layout, it would be great if i could use percentages or auto.

example: if i put height: 300px, it works, but if i use height: auto; or height:30%; it doesn't work.

I know that it doesn't work because i'm using float left.

Why this happens? Is there other way to do that?

css

```
#offerinformations {
    width: 290px;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 15px;
}

#offerlogo {
    width: 294px;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#offerbtns {
    width: 270px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    float: left;
}

#offers{
color:white;
background-color: #262627;
border-left: 5px solid #f15c5c;
height: auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="offers">
<div id="offerinformations">
        <h2>Informations</h2>
        <p>This page demonstrates a 3 column responsive layout.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="offerlogo">
        <h2>Logo</h2>
        <p>This page demonstrates a 3 column responsive layout.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="offerbtns">
        <h2>Buttons</h2>
        <p>This page demonstrates a 3 column responsive layout.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `clearer` before the end of your div ..

It's an element (span, div, p) with the propriety CSS `clear:both;`

[Explanation](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html)